# Is there a non-Google-infested alternative to Tesseract OCR (free command-line OCR software with Windows support)?

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line, ocr

I thought I had found exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Everything was perfect, until I read:

> Since 2006 it is developed by Google.

I would rather not have Google spying on everything I OCR, please.

Is there an alternative which is not infested by Google?

I've looked long and hard and it sadly doesn't seem to be the case. Although I wonder how exactly it's "developed by Google" since nothing about that repo seems to suggest that it is except for that sentence...

Comment: Upvoted for helpful question by a new community member, and for possibly coining the term "non-Google-infested"! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use the open source [GOCR](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gocr). It may not be powerful than tesseract but you may not have concerns regarding data theft.

> gocr is an optical character recognition program that can be used from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract OCR is a free open sourced command line OCR built in C++. Its development is paid by Google, but contributions can be made by anyone.

You can use use Tesseract without giving Google anything. If you are very concerned run it on a **virtual machine that has no network connection**. Personally, it is much easier to set up in Ubuntu "sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-eng libtesseract-dev -y" done! Personally I use it with WSL2 on Windows and use Python to interact with it.